# Преобразование Markdown в HTML

Tags: html, markdown

Как преобразовать `.md`-файл в html и вставить его в определённую часть html-шаблона?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/articles/672266/

Comment: Программы из списка, что я скидывал в прошлом ответе это как-раз и делают. Попробуй например hugo.